# Simple Form non associated model checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, simple-form

I'm running into a couple of problems, some of which, I think I have found a resolution. I'm trying to create a checkbox which will copy already filled in information to another form.

Let me try and paint the picture. I have a `HomeAddress` & `OfficeAddress` that `belong_to` a `User`. While many people are working from home these days, these addresses can both be the same, so when creating a `User`, I want them to be able to check a box which will copy the address information from `HomeAddress` to the `OfficeAddress` input fields.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :home_address do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :state %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode %>
<% end %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :office_address do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :copy_home_address, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, input_html: { checked: false id: 'copyPrimaryLocationAddress' } %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :state %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode %>
<% end %>
```

Couple of questions and problems I'm running into to start. Obviously adding the default value `checked: false` allows me to get around having to have this attribute exist on my `OfficeAddress` model. I am aware that I can create my own custom one which I'm fine with as well: `app/inputs/fake_checkbox_input.rb`(unsure how to get it to work):

```
class FakeCheckboxInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  # This method only create a basic input without reading any value from object
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    tag_name = "#{@builder.object_name}[#{attribute_name}]"
    template.check_box_tag(tag_name, options['value'] || 1, options['checked'], options)
  end
end
```

This seems to get by the errors and association to a model that a form field has to have. However, the `value` ALWAYS stays the same. I'm trying to get it so that the value will change depending on when/if the checkbox is checked. Not to mention how to copy the information from the `HomeAddress` to the `OfficeAddress` which is a separate issue I dont know how to resolve.

Any tips on how to resolve or where to start would be helpful. I'm reading through the `SimpleForm` documentation but it just isn't making sense for my given circumstance.

Comment: I would use JS to copy the form fields. The implementation details (React vs. jQuery, webpacker vs. sprockets) are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: You don't have to use the form builder you can just create your own checkbox and when checked copy the information between the inputs via js.

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh definitely, I always like to try and find a solution within the confines of the library that is being used. I'm aware that can be unpractical though.

Comment: @Nappy in this case to implement otherwise would fall into the impractical category. The way I see it your alternative is to: 1) add a virtual attribute to `OfficeAddress`; 2) Ensure that `HomeAddress` persists; 3) Copy the Attributes of `HomeAddress` to `OfficeAddress` then persist `OfficeAddress`. This seems a bit obtuse IMO. Additionally I might recommend that separate models for `HomeAddress` and `OfficeAddress` would be better modeled as `[User] has_many :addresses` and `[Address] belongs_to :address_type` or maybe STI (although I generally shy way from this)